# Why does ssh -f create multiple processes when a pipe is used?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, bash, solaris

When I on my Linux host do

```
ssh -f 10.10.47.47 "/opt/omni/bin/mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8024 | /usr/sbin/zfs receive tank/test"
```

then I see on the remote host

```
 27349 ?        S  0:00 bash -c /opt/omni/bin/mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8024 | /usr/sbin/zfs receive tank/t
 27350 ?        S  0:00 /opt/omni/bin/mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8024
 27351 ?        S  0:00 /usr/sbin/zfs receive tank/test
```

where I would have expected to just see the `27349` process.

**Question**

Why does `ssh -f` create the additional two processes?

And still they mess up `mbuffer` as `-I 8024` sets it up in listening mode on port 8024?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` opens a shell and tell it to execute two programs, `mbuffer` and `zfs` which are connected by a pipe. To do this, the shell needs to fork two more processes, or do you have any idea how they could get executed otherwise?

I don't understand the last sentence. What gets messed up?

Comment: The last sentence: Isn't there now process `27349` and `27350` that are now both listening on port `8024`? And therefore conflict?

Comment: What? Why on earth should the bash now listen on port 8024? The `-I` parameter is send to `mbuffer` and not interpreted by the bash. You seriously need to read up on how Linux/Unix works....